# How to find records that have duplicate data using Active Record

Tags: ruby, activerecord, arel

What is the best way to find records with duplicate values in a column using ruby and the new Activerecord?

Comment: Duplicated values of just 1 column or more than 1? Is/Are these string/ints/text fields?

Comment: just 1 column - strings.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Translating @TuteC into ActiveRecord:

```
sql = 'SELECT id, 
         COUNT(id) as quantity 
         FROM types 
         GROUP BY name 
       HAVING quantity > 1'
#=>
Type.select("id, count(id) as quantity")
  .group(:name)
  .having("quantity > 1")
```

Comment: Is this code supposed to work for PostgreSQL as well? It returns the error `PGError: ERROR:  column "quantity" does not exist`

Comment: @Marc, I am not sure. But you can try `Type.select("id, count(id) as quantity").group(:name).having("count(id) > 1")`

Comment: this will only find exact duplicates.

Comment: @holaSenor - What is a non-exact duplicate, exactly? (pun intended)

Comment: Good question, I'm sure it made sense at the time. I suspect there was another comment, since deleted, that I was responding too. Probably a comment with some code that compared all fields in the row rather than one column, but who knows. Duplicate needs to be qualified by some criteria. By exact I think I meant the proposed code compared all attributes and they would have to be the same, OP wanted to use one column.

Comment: How can I go about having the other columns of the row to work with as well?

Comment: re fl00rs answer: Postgresql - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "types.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.  But add it to the group-by (no error), and then you get zero hits, since no two records have the same id-value.  I've tried several of these solutions, and all either don't return the ID in the result (so who knows where the dups were), or fail to find the desired records when the ID is included.

Comment: Best workaround is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361669/return-duplicate-records-activerecord-postgres  Adapted to this would be:  type_dups = Type.group(:name).having("count(name) > 1").count.keys; @results = Type.where(:name => type_dups)

Answer (score 28):

Here's how I solved it with the AREL helpers, and no custom SQL:

```
Person.select("COUNT(last_name) as total, last_name")
  .group(:last_name)
  .having("COUNT(last_name) > 1")
  .order(:last_name)
  .map{|p| {p.last_name => p.total} }
```

Really, it's just a nicer way to write the SQL. This finds all records that have duplicate last_name values, and tells you how many and what the last names are in a nice hash.

Answer (score 21):

I was beating my head against this problem with a 2016 stack (Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.2), and got what I wanted with this:

```
> Model.select([:thing]).group(:thing).having("count(thing) > 1").all.size
 => {"name1"=>5, "name2"=>4, "name3"=>3, "name4"=>2, "name5"=>2}
```

Comment: this was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 11):

With custom SQL, this finds `types` with same values for `name`:

```
sql = 'SELECT id, COUNT(id) as quantity FROM types
         GROUP BY name HAVING quantity > 1'
repeated = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 2.x, select is a private method of AR class.  Just use find():

```
klass.find(:all, 
  :select => "id, count(the_col) as num", 
  :conditions => ["extra conditions here"], 
  :group => 'the_col', 
  :having => "num > 1")
```

Comment: Totally off-topic, grave-digging comment here... but WHY IS THIS BETTER THAN SQL?

Comment: @JohnCromartie It's not. But it's fun. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that extends the other answers to show how to find and iterate through the records grouped by the duplicate field:

```
duplicate_values = Model.group(:field).having(Model.arel_table[:field].count.gt(1)).count.keys
Model.where(field: duplicate_values).group_by(&:field).each do |value, records|
  puts "The records with ids #{records.map(&:id).to_sentence} have field set to #{value}"
end
```

It seems a shame this has to be done with two queries but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33363923) confirms this approach.